# How to handle windowing/aggregating in Flink on a date-time centric, non-eventtime field?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm somewhat new to stream/event processing and Flink I'm running into the following problem.

I'm working with Invoice events coming from Kafka that have an event "timestamp" as well as a "scheduledAt" date (timestamp) and would like to perform daily aggregations on the invoice 'total'.  In a traditional DB I would do something like:

```
SELECT AVG(total)
FROM "Invoice"
WHERE date_trunc('day', "scheduledAt") = date_trunc('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

However, when considering this in a streaming context, I was attempting to use 'eventtime' (taken from the event 'timestamp') and a 1 day window.  The problem is I'd really like to use the 'scheduledAt' timestamp, however, it's a field that can be changed far in the future from when the event occurs or potentially even back in the past.

At the moment I'm having trouble reconciling how to achieve something similar using streaming/windowing especially when the 'scheduledAt' datetime can change both forward and backward in time.

Are there any suggestions on patterns or techniques in Flink that I might be able to follow to achieve daily averaging in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most obvious use case for streaming, but I'll offer a sketch of how to make it work.

Assuming it's necessary to accommodate all manner of changes to the `scheduledAt` field, then it's necessary to keep enough state around to potentially recalculate everything from first principles.

Here's one way to do that with Flink. Stream in events for invoice creation, as well as for invoice rescheduling (and any sort of update, really). Assuming all of the aggregations are done on a daily basis, key the stream by the equivalent of `date_trunc('day', "scheduledAt")`, so that all invoices for the same day are gathered together.

You could use either windows or a `ProcessFunction` to do the aggregations, but I'll assume a `ProcessFunction`. You can use managed, keyed state to hold all the invoices for each given day, and either emit a stream of continuously updated reports of the day's invoices as new information arrives, or use timers to emit reports at appropriate intervals.

Depending on the aggregations being computed, it may not be necessary to keep all of the invoices in Flink state. You can simply store aggregated values, and update those aggregates as new invoices (and invoice updates) arrive. For example, if you only need to report the average and total for each day, you could keep a counter and a running total in either `ValueState` or `ReducingState`, and compute the average from those. But if you also need to report the maximum invoice, then you'll have to store them all.